# issues creating a qrcode

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone pls help me out!

`<a class="lay">33</a>`    The class text '33' is randomly generated outside my file, post is by js.

What I want to do is to replace `value='work'` with the random code`33`when generated but still keep `class='lay`

```
<input id="txt" type='txt' value="Work" style="Width:20%"/> 

<img id='barcode' src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" alt="" width="50" height="100" />
```

Any method to achieve the same goal would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to get the value from the anchor, and then use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the input field.

```
$("#txt").val($(".lay").text());
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/q7kx2Lyp/1/